How using telebot make a bot send message ONCE in a specific time?
I'm writing a bot using telebot and bot needs to remind the user adbout his departure. I got a departure date, and I need ro sent a message a day before departure. I need to send it just once.
I tried shedule python module and understood, that it can't send message once, and it can't send message in the next month for example, or I don't understand how to make it do this. Can you explain me, please, is there another way to do this or how to make sheduler make that i need?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Please, check the code below. It runs a thread that executes every second and you can program an action at specific time or each n seconds.
Please, note that you have to specify chat_id
#this timer can be used to execute tasks from time to time or at a specific time

import telebot
import time, datetime
import threading 

bot = telebot.TeleBot('TOKEN')


chat_id = None

def tic_tac():

    i = 0

    while True:

        this_moment = datetime.datetime.now()

        #Executes each 60 secondss
        if ((i % 60) == 0):
            if chat_id:
                bot.send_message(chat_id, "Hello! How are you?")

        #Check if it is 12:00:00; if it is true sends the message
        if this_moment.hour == 12 and this_moment.minute == 0 and this_moment.second == 0:
            if chat_id:
                bot.send_message(chat_id, "It is the noon!")

        i += 1
        time.sleep(1)

#Needs to be started to know the chat id to send messages
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def save_chat_id(message):
    global chat_id
    chat_id = message.chat.id 
    bot.send_message(chat_id, 'I got it', reply_to_message_id=message.message_id)



timThr = threading.Thread(target=tic_tac)
timThr.start()
bot.polling(none_stop=True)```


Аh thank you! I'm already desperate to find answer. It works. But I have another little question... So, everytime than people want to bot like this, the run an endless timer? There isn't an option to use computer time, dor instance?
